# Dovecot problems downloading mails

Tags: postfix, imap, dovecot, telnet, mutt

When I run `telnet localhost imap2` both from localhost, using IP from external, `mutt -f imaps://lasse@"mydomain"@localhost` and using webmail, I can view my messages. 
But If I run `mutt -f imaps://lasse@"mydomain"` or using Thunderbird I can not  read my mails from IMAP. I have no problems yesterday, but the problem came today.
I have followed this guide, when I set up the programs http://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze

What can be wrong?

My server is running Debian with kernel 2.6.32, Dovecot version 1.2.15 and Postfix version 2.7.1
I have not made any updates to Dovecot, and new e-mails arrives (I have checked it using webmail (Squirrelmail))

**EDIT**
I moved the computer to another network, and now I get the error
`imap-login: Info: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip="oneip", lip="server-ip", TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14094417:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert illegal parameter` in `dovecot.log`, but what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does "mydomain" resolve to (DNS)? As you can access your mail using IP and on localhost, the first thing I would check is if "mydomain" resolves to an ip on the server on which dovecot listens... .

Comment: "mydomain" is multiple, but one of them is `the87boy.dk`